# Create a new column in tibble with percentage of total per year

Tags: r

I've successfully transformed the first Tibble to the second one as shown below:

1.

```
# Animal    Food    2015    2016

Monkey      Banana   54     65
Monkey      Hotdog   43     76
## # ... with 54 more rows
```

2. 

```
# Animal    Year   Banana  Hotdog

Monkey      2015    54      43
Monkey      2016    65      76
## # ... with 54 more rows
```

Now I would like to create a new column where the percentage of Hotdogs is showing with this code:

```
df$hotdog_percent <- with(df, "Hotdog" / ( "Hotdog" + "Banana") )
```

However, I get the error **non-numeric argument to binary operator**. I've tried the below code to transform the original columns to numeric without success.

```
df$Banana <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Banana)) %>%
df$Hotdog <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Hotdog))
```

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this without quoting in `with`

```
df$Banana <- as.numeric(df$Banana)
df$Hotdog <- as.numeric(df$Hotdog)

df$hotdog_percent <- with(df, Hotdog / (Hotdog + Banana) )
```

- output

```
 Animal Year Banana Hotdog hotdog_percent
1 Monkey 2015     54     43      0.4432990
2 Monkey 2016     65     76      0.5390071
```

Comment: I'm still getting "non-numeric argument to binary operator".

Comment: Try this update

Comment: I got this message: Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 430 rows [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ...].
Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `Hotdog`.

Comment: Would you `dput(df)` and print the output?

Comment: I'm sorry, don't know what dput(df) means. However I got this: Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `Hotdog`.
Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `Banana`. I guess one problem could be that my data frame I'm recalling in the code is the original and not the desired tibble I created. Maybe I need to "copy" or how to say it so it can identity the new columns?

Comment: just print `dput(df) ` where `df` is your data.frame and  copy the output and past it in your question.